# gcsfuse mount exits with status 1

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine, gcsfuse

trying to use gcsfuse, but when I run

```
gcsfuse <bucket> /target/dir
```

I keep getting this error

```
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: fusermount: exit status 1
```

I'm doing this from a GCE instance with full API access permissions to Google Cloud services

The folder exists and I'm in the fuse group.

I tried running with all the debug switches, but they reveal nothing helpful

```
> gcsfuse --uid "33" --gid "33" --debug_fuse --debug_gcs --debug_http --debug_invariants bucket-name /target/dir
Using mount point: /target/dir
Opening GCS connection...
Opening bucket...
Mounting file system...
daemonize.Run: readFromProcess: sub-process: mountWithArgs: mountWithConn: Mount: mount: fusermount: exit status 1
```

version info: gcsfuse version 0.15.0 (Go version go1.5.2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

my /target/dir was  owned by www-data:fuse, but the group didn't have write permission on the directory before mounting.

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!

Comment: I am getting the same error from datalab. i chmod a+w target/dir and still getting the same error. any idea how to avoid that error when mounting a bucket to datalab. Thanks

Comment: It'd sure help if gcsfuse printed an error message that helped with problem solving. Are you up for filling this as an issue on GitHub?

Comment: How to change the group write permissions?

Answer (score 11):

I had the same issue, as I was trying to mount a folder on a docker container. However, there it turned out to be that the container needs to run in privileged mode in order for gcsfuse to work.

> docker --privileged docker-image-name

The above command works fine. Alternatively, if anyone is using kubernetes, the security context needs to be specified as follows:

> ```
>   containers:
>   - name: application-name
>     securityContext:
>       privileged: true
> ```

Comment: If using docker compose, add `privileged: true` in your definition of that particular container [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#domainname-hostname-ipc-mac_address-privileged-read_only-shm_size-stdin_open-tty-user-working_dir)

Answer (score 5):

I got very same error message but solution was rather different. The principal ServiceAccount was missing permission to this bucket

BUT

I was able to find it out when running following debug flags in command

```bash
gcsfuse --foreground --debug_fuse --debug_fs --debug_gcs --debug_http -o nonempty  bucket_name /local/mount/folder
```

gcsfuse version 0.41.6 (Go version go1.18.4) | Centos7

Answer (score 0):

In my case I found that although the mount folder has read/write permission both for user and group, some subfolders didn't have write permission for the group. This happened because these folder were mounted in a docker container.

For this case just add group permission with

```
sudo chmod g+w /mnt/folder/mysubfolder
```

However, sometimes you cannot mount the bucket as it's just that you need to be `root` user; this happens if you switch off a VM. In this case just access as root and mount the bucket:

```
sudo -sH
sudo gcsfuse --uid $(id -u) --gid $(id -g) --dir-mode 775 --file-mode 775 -o allow_other mybucket /mnt/myfolder
```

Answer (score -1):

Hey Please clear the mount folder inside that directory file should be not visible otherwise it won't work

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).